# Fullcalendar - Aggregate collapsible event groups

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'd like to create a system like in picture found from this request: https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-scheduler/issues/95

I need a PARENT GROUP EVENT with an entire line (in pic: REPLACE FOOTPATH under PARKS& COMMUNITY SERVICES) with a little down arrow on the right show me the CHILDREN EVENTS (in orange in the example) in collapsable mode.

I need to move all subevents group moving the PARENT EVENT. And i need to do a resizing on a subevent so also the PARENT EVENT get resized...

I don't know how to start... i need help for a little working exampe. Thanks

[image: See 4th line with collapsable event]

UPDATE: if PARENT EVENTS are not implementable, basically i need a concatenated events in the same RESOURCES, in the same LINE, like pic:

Example: RESOURCE Auditorium B have SUBEVENT 1 CHAIN green in the same line. and SUBEVENT 2 CHAIN orange in the same line without carring-line

[image]

UPDATE 2: Ok I know for RESOURCE GROUPING but is not what i need... basically in the example above, the workaround is to create a RESOURCE for every chain of event... so if I have 100 CHAIN of events, i need 100 RESOURCE. My intent is: if I have a CHAIN not overlapping another CHAIN OF EVENT, then i can set multiple chain on the same line. See pic. The best is to have only 1 RESOURCE line....

My JSFIDDLE:

https:// jsfiddle.net/outecxnb/8/

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by "children events"? This is some custom data structure of your own, I assume? I don't think FullCalendar or Scheduler supports any such concept. From reading that link you gave, the fullCalendar maintainer said "Will probably only attack it once there's more proven demand.". So actually you should contribute to that thread, like others have done, to register your interest in this feature.

Comment: Example: I have a parent EVENT named: TRIP. But this event is made by detailed subevents like: TRAVEL BY BUS, LUNCH-TIME, VISIT TO MUSEUM, DINNER, RETURN TRAVEL. Basically i need to handle all subevents like ONE event.

Comment: You'd have to clarify the exact meaning of "handle" - I presume it covers a number of tasks which might need to be done to those grouped events? But basically that's quite a significant change, I think. More work than is suitable for an SO question. Unless you have done anything yourself on it already, and just need part of it fixing or completing?

Comment: I've update original post to explain what i need.

Comment: Resources can be grouped, and can have children, which would achieve a similar visual effect to your "what I need" screenshot. See the source code of https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-scheduler-1.8.1/demos/grouping.html (e.g. the "Auditorium D" example. In your case you could have "main" and "sub-event" divisions within that)

Comment: Ok this now seems to be a different problem from the original from what I can see. How are the chains linked in the example here? Is one chain a child of another? Can multiple chains have the same parent? How even do you define a "chain", if they are all from the same resource? It's not clear. My last suggestion was based on you having sub-events of a parent event. I can't see how that structure would work with your new suggestion where there are multiple lines of events with unspecified links to each other. BTW are you basically trying to re-create Visio using fullCalendar, by any chance?

Comment: In the example... every chain as a common "resourceId" to work. My goal is to create only 1 resource (basically a useless timeline) where I can put several CHAIN...a chain is made by sequentially events like example. Because a CHAIN is made by multiple events, IN A NORMAL FULLCALENDAR MODE if I overlap 2 CHAIN like UPDATE1 example above, the chain break in 2 lines.....I need to handle a chain like a unique EVENT...so a CHAIN need to occupe ALWAYS a single line (row).

Comment: So I thinked about original post request by doing a unique PARENT EVENT (to prevent break lines) and add a collapsable button to show the events children... but i understod this method is not possible and I'm looking for a solution to use my UPDATE2 example with sequentially events BUT using only a RESOURCE LINE...sorry for my english

Comment: That functionality just doesn't exist. You'd have to create it yourself by modifying fullCalendar or Scheduler source code itself. That's a lot of work and too broad for an SO question. The only workaround I can think of would be to use child resources / resource grouping, but your server would need to work out in advance which chains overlap, before sending the data to fullCalendar, and assign the chains to resource groups accordingly to create the correct effect. But it would not stay like that if you start dragging/dropping them to different times.